# How to mask attack a sha256 hash with following information using hashcat?

Tags: hash, brute-force, sha256, hashcat, twitter

I am hashcat newbie and I want to crack a hash :)

The answer is 1-15 (unknown) characters and it may contain 'a-z' 'A-Z' '0-9' and '_' . (A Twitter username)

How may I mask attack a hash with above information using hashcat?

The brute force (below) takes SO much time...:

```
hashcat -a 3 -m 1400 myhash
```

Comment: Do you know whether or not the plaintext was human-generated, or randomly generated?

Comment: You need some more information to be able to do better than brute force - are there any password rules (e.g. must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one digit) which you can use to reduce the search space? For human generated passwords, wordlists will often give quicker results, but they don't help with randomly generated passwords from things like KeePass.